# Troubles with subnets and redirections

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

What I want to create is 2 subnets that communicate each other through a gateway.

Here is my gateway:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW c4:46:19:69:b7:a5  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::c646:19ff:fe69:b7a5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:987185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:635513 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:1300656767 (1.3 GB)  Byte TX:86680631 (86.6 MB)

wlan0:1   Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW c4:46:19:69:b7:a5  
          indirizzo inet:172.16.1.1  Bcast:172.16.1.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

wlan0:2   Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW c4:46:19:69:b7:a5  
          indirizzo inet:172.16.2.1  Bcast:172.16.2.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

and its route table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
172.16.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

In a similar way on 2 pc launching:

```
ifconfig wlan0:1 172.16.1.2/24
route add default gw 172.16.1.1
```

and

```
ifconfig wlan0:1 172.16.2.2/24
route add default gw 172.16.2.1
```

what happens is the following: at the beginning all works fine, if I make a ping from 172.16.2.2 to 172.16.1.2 it goes through the gateway, but I don't know why at a certain point it stops I mean 172.16.2.2 can send a packet to 172.16.1.2 without passing through the gateway, even if I turn down the gateway they continue to ping each other.

What's going on?

Comment: Can you provide a network map showing how the networks are physically connected? If the .2.x subnet can ping the .1.x subnet even if the gateway machine is OFF, something is wrong... sounds like they are all connected on the same physical network. or am I missing something here?

Comment: Before launching every command every machine is connected to the same physical network i.d. wlan0 per every machine is 192.168.43.X